# How to create a SWIG typemap for functions that return specific type

Tags: c++, lua, swig, typemaps

I'm trying to create a SWIG typemap for functions that return specific type.

For example, this is my C++ function

```
t_float get()
{
    return 3.14159;
}
```

`t_float` is defined to either `float` or `double` depending on the `#define` setting on one header file. And it seems the SWIG `i` file cannot read the defined symbols in that file even when I include the header in `i` file.

So, I decided to create a typemap for this function so `t_float` type can be converted to `lua_number`.

But I have no idea how to create a typemap for functions that return a value.

I tried to do it myself but I couldn't make it.

```
%typemap(out) t_float
{
    lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number)($output));
}
```

How to correctly create a typemap so I can make `get()` return a number value in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  After pushing the result to the stack you also have to increase the number of return values which is stored in `SWIG_arg`.  I only found out after I took a look at the internal typemaps of SWIG.  (An identifier called `$output` doesn't exist).

*N.B.:* Please immediately drop the habit of explicitly casting values to the desired type.  This is dangerous because if the type does not match, you are telling the compiler “interpret this bit pattern as the desired type anyway, *I know what I'm doing*”.  Just let the compiler do the implicit conversion for you.  You will also receive a compiler error if the types are not convertible, which is much better than a segmentation fault or garbage values at runtime.  See this [Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rxOx2QW8MPLGIqP7) for a demonstration and note that there are no compiler warnings!

```
%module t_float
%{
typedef double t_float;
t_float get() {
    return 3.14159;
}
%}

%include <typemaps.i>

%typemap(out) t_float {
    lua_pushnumber(L, $1);
    ++SWIG_arg;
}

t_float get();
```

```lua
local t_float = require("t_float")
print(t_float.get())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But isn't `static_cast` safe to use?  I think it generates compiler warning.

Comment: @ZackLee `static_cast` is only safe for values.  It still allows you to cast `void*` to anything you want.  My compiler does not produce a warning.  If yours does, please at least use `static_cast` instead of the C-style cast.

Comment: I will, Thank you Sir!